# How does networking work in QEMU's guest OS?

Tags: networking, operating-system, host, qemu

I've got a problem about understanding how Qemu and network in guest OS (Ubuntu) work. I've read [this manual](http://qemu-buch.de/cgi-bin/moin.cgi/QemuAndTuntap) and others. And if I understand, if you want to pick up Internet in guest OS you need to make **tap** interface in host OS. After then to link **eth0** and **tap0** interfaces:

1. By using NAT-routing
2. By using bridge ( link **tap0** and **eth0-host**)

Now I have these interfaces in host (**ppp0** - 3G-modem - Internet, lo):

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:10.245.146.78  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:49635 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:42745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:52405401 (52.4 MB)  TX bytes:5988643 (5.9 MB)
```

In gust OS (**eth0**, lo):

```
eth0        Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr:52:54:00:12:34:56
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
      ...
```

> **Internet in gust OS work! How and why is working network in guest OS if I don't have link between real ppp0 and guest interface? I haven't even anyone interface in host for guest OS.**

If I understand that's because guest forward data through default host interface. But why?

Qemu options:

```
qemu -hda ~/virt.disk -cdrom /dev/cdrom -boot once=dc -m 1024M -usb -smp 2 -enable-kvm
```

Host routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.64.64.64     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
default         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
```

Guest routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0 U    1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0   U    1000   0        0 eth0
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0       UG   0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to use the TAP device but having problems with it.
To use TAP you should have something like this to your qemu command line:

```
-net nic,model=rtl8139 -net tap
```

In those arguments, replace *rtl8139* with any available nic device on your machine. If you don’t know the available nic devices use the following command to list them:

```
qemu -net nic,model=?
```

You also must insure that the TAP device is created.  The following script create the necessary bridge and ports:

```
# For Network Bridging/TAP
# Set permissions of tun device
chown root.users /dev/net/tun 
chmod g+rw /dev/net/tun

#Add a bridge, add eth0
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc
brctl addif br0 eth0
dhclient br0

# Create tap0
tunctl -t tap0 -u username #replace username by your username

# Enable tap0
brctl addif br0 tap0
ifconfig tap0 up
```

After running this script, VMs started with the *-net tap* arguments should be network ready and using TAP.

Comment: When I run this, following error is coming. qemu-system-i386: -net tap: Device 'tap' could not be initialized